# How to list files under a folder using jenkins

Tags: file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am able to find the files under the checked out git repo with the following code

```
stage('Clone and Upload') {
     steps {
       git branch: params.GIT_BRANCH, credentialsId: 'my-bitbucket-id', url: params.GIT_REPO
       script {
   
           def files = findFiles excludes: '', glob: ''
               
           files.each { f -> 
               if (f.directory && f.name == 'MyScripts'){
                   echo "Folder: $f.name"   // Prints Folder: MyScripts
               }
           }
       }
     }
   }
```

But I want to list all the files inside 'MyScripts' folder next. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following.

```
def files = findFiles excludes: '', glob: ''

files.each { f -> 
   if (f.directory && f.name == 'MyScripts'){
       echo "Folder: $f.name"   // Prints Folder: MyScripts
       dir('MyScripts') {
          sh "pwd"
          def fileList = findFiles(glob: '*.*')
          echo "$fileList"
        } 
   }
}
```